# How to fit multiple Background images in react native (responsive)

Tags: javascript, react-native, responsive-design

I have two background images which are not fitting on different devices.

I tried with `<ImageBackground>` and `absolute` % calculation.

iPhone 12 (right performing):

[image: iPhone 12 (right performing):]

iPhone 12 Pro Max (wrong performing):

[image]

Has anyone a idea how to solve this responsive problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to watch this video to get an idea how to do it without images https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmEFmR4SBP0&list=PLkOyNuxGl9jyhndcnbFcgNM81fZak7Rbw&index=25&t=895s

Comment: Thats what i was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't set the height or width of an `<ImageBackground/>` it won't show.
2. Next in order to overlay an `<ImageBackground/>` over other another you need to set the `zIndex:1` to be 1 or higher then the other's zIndex. And make them `position: 'absolute'`
3. Lastly if you want the borderRadius to show in an `<ImageBackground/>` set `overflow: 'hidden'`

Here's a full example below (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/suspicious-celery)